# Show that the number $A$ is irrational

Tags: solution-verification, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

**question**

For each $n$ natural number we denote by $a_n$ the first digit a
of the number $n^3$.

Show that the number $A = 0, a_1a_2 ... a_n ...$ is irrational.

**my idea**

A thing is clear....between $a_1$ and the last digit of $A$ is an infinity of numbers.

This means we have to show that the first digit of $n^3$ doesn't follow a rule.

I thought of showing it with modular arithmetic. I don't know where to start. I also did a table with the first 20 numbers raised to the 3rd power, but I didn't find anything that could help me.

**EDIT WITH MY IDEA FOR @5xum**

As I said, we have to show that if $10^x≤a^3≤2∗10^x$, $10^y≤b^3≤2∗10^y$
and $x<y$, then b has more solutions than a.

We can write the 2 inequality as  $\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^x} \leq a \leq \sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^x*2} $ and  $\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^y} \leq b \leq \sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^y*2}$, which means that we basically have to show that

$\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^x} -\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^x*2} \leq \sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^y} -\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^y*2}$

$\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^x} (\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{2}-1) \leq \sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^y}(\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{2}-1) $

$\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^x} \leq \sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{10^y}$, which is true because $x<y$.

Is my idea right?

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Find a reason that prevents the sequence $(a_n)$ from being ultimly periodic.

Comment: Try, for instance, to show that there are arbitrarily long blocks with of consecutive equal digits.

Comment: "the first digit a..." : is this the leftmost digit or the rightmost digit?

Comment: @user2661923 Like the first digitof 120 Is 1.

Comment: Is the following number rational or irrational $$0.10110111011110111110\cdots ~? ~$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 5xum's hint is helpful.

Let $f(n)$ be the number of integers $m$ such that
$$10^n\le m^3\lt 2\cdot 10^n\tag1$$

In the following, let us prove that for $n\ge 1$, $f(n+1)\gt f(n)$ holds.

$(1)$ is equivalent to
$$10^{\frac n3}\le m\lt 2^{\frac 13}\cdot 10^{\frac n3}\tag2$$
so we can write
$$f(n)=\left\lfloor 2^{\frac 13}\cdot 10^{\frac n3}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil 10^{\frac n3}\right\rceil +1$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ represents the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$, and $\lceil x\rceil$ represents the least integer greater than or equal to $x$.

Since $f(1)=0,f(2)=1$ and $f(3)=3$, we have
$$f(1)\lt f(2)\lt f(3)$$

For $n\ge 3$, we have
$$\begin{align}&f(n+1)-f(n)
\\\\&=\left\lfloor 2^{\frac 13}\cdot 10^{\frac {n+1}3}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil 10^{\frac {n+1}3}\right\rceil +1
\\&\quad -\bigg(\left\lfloor 2^{\frac 13}\cdot 10^{\frac n3}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil 10^{\frac n3}\right\rceil +1\bigg)
\\\\&=\left\lfloor 2^{\frac 13}\cdot 10^{\frac {n+1}3}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil 10^{\frac {n+1}3}\right\rceil
\\&\quad -\left\lfloor 2^{\frac 13}\cdot 10^{\frac n3}\right\rfloor+\left\lceil 10^{\frac n3}\right\rceil\tag3\end{align}$$

Using
$$x-1\lt \lfloor x\rfloor\le x$$
$$x\le \lceil x\rceil\lt x+1$$
we have
$$\begin{align}(3)&\gt 2^{\frac 13}\cdot 10^{\frac {n+1}3}-1-\bigg(10^{\frac {n+1}3}+1\bigg)
\\&\quad -\bigg(2^{\frac 13}\cdot 10^{\frac n3}\bigg)+10^{\frac n3}
\\\\&=2^{\frac 13}\cdot 10^{\frac n3}
(10^{\frac 13}-1)
\\&\quad -10^{\frac n3}(10^{\frac 13}-1)-2\\\\&=10^{\frac n3}(10^{\frac 13}-1)(2^{\frac 13}-1)-2\tag4\end{align}$$

Since $10^{\frac 13}\gt 2.1$ (which is equivalent to $10\gt 9.261$ which is true) and $2^{\frac 13}\gt \frac 54$ (which is equivalent to $2\gt \frac{125}{64}$ which is true), we have

$$\begin{align}(4)&\gt (2.1)^n\times 1.1\times \frac 14-2
\\\\&\gt 2^n\times 1.1\times\frac 14-2
\\\\&\ge 2^3\times 1.1\times \frac 14-2
\\\\&=2.2-2
\\\\&\gt 0\end{align}$$

Therefore, we can say that for $n\ge 1$, $f(n+1)\gt f(n)$ holds.

---

**Another solution** :

For every positive integer $k$, we have
$$a_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $10^k\le n\le 10^k+10^{k-1}$}
\\\\ 8&\text{if $n=2\cdot 10^k$}\end{cases}$$

So, we can say that $A$ is irrational. (I think you see why we can say so.)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Think about how many perfect cubes there are between $10$ and $20$, how many between $100$ and $200$, how many between $1000$ and $2000$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint, but I don't understand how this is going to help got to the proof we want to prove. Can you be more explicit? Thank you!

Comment: @IONELABUCIU For every $n$ such that $n^3$ is between $1000$ and $2000$, the corresponding digit of $A$ will be... what?

Comment: It will be the digit  1?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Exactly. Now, compare the number of values $n$ such that $n^3$ is between $1000$ and $2000$, and compare that to the number of $n$ for which $n^3$ is between $1000000$ and $2000000$. What do you notice?

Comment: Between 1000 and 2000 are 3 numbers and between 1000000 and 2000000 are 24 numbers....

Comment: @IONELABUCIU OK... so what do you think happens when you increase the number of zeroes?

Comment: we get more and more cubes between  the numbers

Comment: @IONELABUCIU OK. Now try to use that fact in your original problem. Don't just answer my questions, try to look at the bigger picture.

Comment: I tried, but i don't understand how is this going to help us? Is it because the number of digits of 1 in a row will increase, so we wouldn't be able to write it as a periodic number?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU You are on the right track with that last question, yes. Think of it this way. If a number is rational, then from some point on, it has a repeating pattern, right? In that case, there exists some "maximal length of consecutive ones" in the number, correct? On the other hand, for your number $A$, the length of consecutive chunks of ones just keeps getting bigger and bigger...

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Do you have any more questions?

Comment: Yes, I have one more question to clarify. Can we demonstrate the fact this fact: that the bigger the numbers are the more cubes are between them? Is there any way other than counting them?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Yes. this fact can be proven. No, you don't have to count them. It is enough to find some real interval $[a_n, b_n]$ such that all integers in that interval cube to something between $10^n$ and $2\cdot 10^n$.

Comment: I dont really understand!

Comment: @IONELABUCIU I am sorry but I will not solve the exercise for you. I gave more than enough hints, it is time for you to do some mathematics.

Comment: The thing is I don't understand how I can turn the examples into something general. All I know is that I have to show that if $10^x\leq a^3\leq 2*10^x$, $10^t\leq b^3 \leq 2*10^y$ and $x<y$, then $b$ has more solutions than $a$,

Comment: i made an edit. Can you please look at it?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU "we have to show that if $10^x≤a^3≤2∗10^x$, $10^y≤b^3≤2∗10^y$
 and $x<y$, then $b$ has more solutions than $a$." This sentence makes no sense. What do you mean by "$b$ has more solutions"? $b$ is just a variable. Your formulation of the problem is not what I am saying for this whole time. **My** point is that as $n$ increases large, the number of **integers** with cubes that start with $1$ and have $n+1$ digits also increases.